# Path-connectedness of $\mathbb{C}\setminus \lbrace z_1, ..., z_n \rbrace$

Tags: general-topology, complex-analysis, path-connected

Today I was thinking about the fact that $\mathbb{C} \setminus \lbrace z_1, ..., z_n \rbrace$ is path-connected. I know how to prove that, just constructing a path joining two points, but I was wondering : is there a way to prove this using the fact that the image of a path-connected space by a continuous function is path-connected ?

More precisely, it is possible prove that $\mathbb{C} \setminus \lbrace z_1, ..., z_n \rbrace$ is path-connected by defining explicitely a surjective continuous function $f : X \rightarrow  \mathbb{C} \setminus \lbrace z_1, ..., z_n \rbrace$, where $X$ is a path-connected topological space ?

For the case $n=1$, using $\exp : \mathbb{C} \rightarrow \mathbb{C}^*$ works, but I was not able to generalize that in the case you remove more than one point.

Thanks for your help !

Comment: One thing to note is that there cannot exist a surjective holomorphic function $\mathbb{C} \to \mathbb{C}\setminus \{z_1, \dots, z_n\}$ for $n > 1$. This is called [Picard's Little Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Picard_theorem).

Comment: @diracdeltafunk Thank you for the comment. Indeed, this gives a reason why I couldn't find a function given by a "nice" formula ! But what I am looking for just requires the function to be continuous, do you know a way I could proceed ?

Comment: Honestly, I don't. I'm sure there is a reasonable proof along these lines (my guess is that the domain of the function should be a compact surface of genus $n-1$ with a point removed), but I don't quite see how to do it.

Comment: Your question "Is it possible to define explicitly a surjective continuous function $f : X \rightarrow  \mathbb{C} \setminus \lbrace z_1, ..., z_n \rbrace$, where $X$ is a path-connected topological space?" does not make much sense. We can take the identity on $\mathbb{C} \setminus \lbrace z_1, ..., z_n \rbrace$. I guess you ask whether we can take $X = \mathbb C$ or something like that.

Comment: @PaulFrost OP is looking for a non-circular proof that $\mathbb{C} \setminus \{z_1, \dots, z_n\}$ is path-connected, so the identity map would not be a good answer. I agree that the question is really "is there an easily-explicitly-describable continuous surjection $X \to \mathbb{C} \setminus \{z_1, \dots, z_n\}$ where $X$ is easily seen to be path connected?" Of course this is subjective, but I think it's a perfectly reasonable question to ask.

Comment: @diracdeltafunk Then OP should edit his question to make precise (or at least *somewhat more* precise) what he/you expect.

Comment: You may note it's not my question :) But imo OP did make this reasonably clear. How would someone read the question, as currently written, and think OP is looking for a circular argument?

Comment: @diracdeltafunk I am aware what OP expects. But do you think that expectation and formulation agree?

Comment: @PaulFrost Thanks for the comment. If you read carefully, my question is not "is it possible to define a function...", but "is it possible to prove that $\mathbb{C} \setminus \lbrace z_1, ..., z_n \rbrace$ is path-connected by defining...". So I guess the formulation matches the expectation here.

Answer (score 2):

First of all, the explanation "just constructing a path joining two points" proves absolutely nothing. I suggest, you write a careful proof of path-connectedness of $Z^c$ which is the complement to a given finite subset $Z\subset {\mathbb C}$ and compare complexity of the proof to the complexity of your proof that ${\mathbb C}^*$ is path-connected (it hinges upon proving continuity and surjectivity of the complex exponential function $\exp: {\mathbb C}\to  {\mathbb C}^*$: Proving this from scratch is a nontrivial challenge).

No, let's prove path-connectivity of $Z^c= {\mathbb C}\setminus Z$ along the lines of your request.

1. First, consider a finite subset $W\subset  {\mathbb R} \subset {\mathbb C}$. Then $W^c$ is the union of two subsets $U^+, U^-$, where
   $$
   U^+=\{z: Im(z)\ge 0\}\setminus W$$
   and
   $$
   U^-=\{z: Im(z)\le 0\}\setminus W.$$
   In fact, both sets are homeomorphic via the complex conjugation map. I claim that $U^+$ is path-connected. Indeed, it is star-like with respect to the point $i$: For each $z\in U^+$ the line segment $[i, z]$ between $i$ and $z$ is contained in $U^+$. I will leave it for you to verify that each star-like subset of  ${\mathbb C}$ is path-connected. (Concatenate two segments $[p, i], [i,q]$ to connect points $p, q\in U^+$.) It follows that $U^-$ is path-connected as well. Observe that $U^+\cap U^-\ne \emptyset$, which implies path-connectivity of  the union $U^+\cup U^-=W^c$.
2. Second, I will use the fact that if $W, Z$ are two subsets of the same cardinality in ${\mathbb C}$ then there exists a homeomorphism $h: {\mathbb C}\to {\mathbb C}$ sending $W$ bijectively to $Z$, see for instance [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4059690/is-the-bbbr2-setminus-p-1-p-n-plane-homeomorphic-to-bbbr2-setm) for an explicit construction.

Thus, given aby finite subset $Z\subset {\mathbb C}$, I find a finite subset $W\subset 
 {\mathbb R} \subset {\mathbb C}$ of the same cardinality and, hence, a homeomorphism
$$
f: X:= W^c\to Z^c
$$
obtained by restricting the homeomorphism $h$. This is the continuous surjective function from a connected space $X$ to $Z^c$ you asked for.

Needless to say, this is much more complex than the standard direct proof of path-connectivity of $Z^c$.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer. Obviously, I know that what I am looking for is not the most direct way to prove this classical fact (and don't worry, I know how to make a rigorous proof of it, and I also know how to prove quickly that $\exp$ is continuous and surjective). My question was rather a curiosity question... Anyway, I understand your answer, but to be a little bit annoying, it does not really answer my question : indeed, your answer relies mostly on the fact that $W^c$ is path-connected, but you prove it by constructing paths, which is precisely what I hoped to avoid.

Comment: But thanks again for your answer and your time, I appreciate !

Comment: @Henry: Your proof that ${\mathbb C}^*$ is path-connected is also by constructing paths: When you prove that ${\mathbb C}$ is path-connected. It is unavoidable that at some point you have to construct paths in some space if you want to prove that a space is path-connected.

Comment: I understand your point, and I kind of agree with you. However, the fact that $\mathbb{C}$ is path-connected is really more elementary than the fact that $Z^c$ is path-connected, whereas, in my opinion, the fact that $W^c$ is path-connected is not so much easier than for $Z^c$. Again, my question was not about a formal rigorous proof, but rather a curiosity : can we explicit a continuous surjective map $f : X \rightarrow Z^c$, where $X$ is "obviously" path-connected. I admit that mathematically speaking, it might seem stupid and useless, but I am curious about that.

Comment: @Henry: "obviously" (applied to path-connected or anything else) is a subjective term that varies from person to person: What you find obvious somebody else might not and vice versa. I suggest you edit your question to make it objectively answerable. In the current form, it is not. For instance, you may require $X$ to be a convex subset in a finite-dimensional vector space: Would you find this "obviously" path-connected? No other space? If so, make this requirement a part of the  question.