# Proving a map of the unit disk fixing the boundary is a homeomorphism

Tags: general-topology, continuity, manifolds

The question is posed in [A homeomorphism of B^n fixing the boundary?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1517052/a-homeomorphism-of-bn-fixing-the-boundary) of constructing a homeomorphism $h$ of the closed unit disk $D^n$ that maps the origin $0$ to a given point $p$ in the open ball $B^n$ while preserving the bounding sphere $S^{n-1}$.

The construction proffered in https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1517119/32337
only describes the map $h$ indirectly. If I correctly understand the description, it amounts to defining $h( 0) = p$ and, for $z \neq p$, defining $h(z) = (1 - \|{z}\|) p + \|{z}\| (1/\|{z}\|) z$, that is, $h(z) = (1 - \|{z}\|) p + z$. Geometrically, as in the answer cited above, this linearly maps the radial segment from $0$ to the boundary point $(1/\|z\|) z$ onto the line segment from $p$ to that same boundary point.

It is clear that $h$, so defined, is injective, continuous, maps $D^n$ into itself, and preserves the boundary points.

**Question:** how to prove that $h^{-1}$ is also continuous.

I belive that $h^{-1}$ is obtained as follows. First, set $\zeta( p) = 0$ and, for $w \neq 0$, set $\zeta(w) = (1 - s) p + s w$ where $s$ is the greater of the two real roots of the quadratic equation $\|{(1 - s) p + s w}\|^2 = 1$. Then
$h^{-1}(w) = (\|{w - p}\|/\|{\zeta(w) -p}\|)\,\zeta(w)$. Geometrically, $h^{-1}(w)$ is obtained by extending the directed line segment from $p$ to $w$ until it hits the boundary $S^{n-1}$ and then mapping the segment from $p$ to that boundary point linearly onto the line segment from $0$ to that same boundary point.

It is easy to see that $h^{-1}$, so defined, is continuous at all points $w \neq 0$.

But how does one show directly that $h^{-1}$ is also continuous at the point $p$?

Comment: Do you know that a continuous bijection of compact Hausdorff spaces is a homeomorphism?

Comment: @MoisheKohan: Yes, of course I know that it suffices to show that $h$ is a continuous bijction of the compact disk. But I was hoping to be able to establish continuity of $h^{-1}$ at $p$ directly.

Comment: Does the answer of user 987 help? [See here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3938735/mathbbrn-is-a-strongly-locally-homogeneous-space).

Comment: @Ulli: Yes that answer by user 987 does establish that $h^{-1}$ is continuous (and everything else needed). I'd still like to see continuity of $h^{-1}$ at $p$ established using the formula I have for it.