# Homeomorphism of $D^2$ onto itself

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology

I am a student studying Algebraic topology. While studying, I have a question following:

> Q1. Let $h$ be any homeomorphism which maps closed disk $D^2$ onto itself. Then does $h$ maps the center of $D^2$ onto the center of it? Can I generalize this to $D^n$?

This question is from the think that $h$ should be continuous. I really tried hard to find some counterexamples, but I failed. Please help me... This is not my homework, I swear. I am really curious about this.

Comment: No. There are plenty of self-homeomorphisms of the closed unit disk (and of higher dimensional unit balls) which don't fix the origin. For instance, you could imagine a homeomorphism that slides everything to the right, but it slides progressively slower as we approach the boundary (until the boundary itself is actually fixed). See also [here](https://demonstrations.wolfram.com/HomeomorphismOfADiskMappingTheOriginToAnotherInteriorPoint/) for more examples

Comment: It's a good question and here is another question/answer on it.  The link above led me to this.  While such an $h$ does not have to fix the origin, it has to fix *some point* that is an old and basic theorem in topology and one of the first that the machinery of AT gave a simple and clean proof of. https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1517052/a-homeomorphism-of-bn-fixing-the-boundary/1517119#1517119

Comment: there are very concrete examples by using Möbius transformations

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is definitely not true in any dimension. One easy explicit way to see this is to use the fact that there are models of hyperbolic $n$-space given by the open $n$-disk. Isometries correspond to certain homeomorphisms of the open disk all of which can be continuously extended to the homeomorphisms of the closed disk. Furthermore, it is well known that the group of hyperbolic isometries acts transitively on hyperbolic space and that point stabilizers are infinite (Lie) groups. Therefore, given any two points in the interior of the disk there are uncountably many homeomorphisms of the closed disk mapping the first point to the second.